# Detect which field is causing duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I am designing a table and during testing it was found that one of the fields causes duplicate rows (which it shouldn't).

As a precaution, I would like to rule out possible duplicates in any other field. How would I go about checking which one of my columns causes duplicate PK's?

Intuitive method:

```
Select 
    count(*),  
    pk_field,  
    other_field1 
from  
    table 
group by  
    pk_field,  
    other_field 
having  
    count(*) > 1  
    and count(distinct other_field1) >1;
```

I want to make sure that if I run this query it will rule out 100% that there are no duplicates caused by other_field1 (that there is only one value of other_field1 for each value of PK).

Extra bonus: is there a query that would show me directly which fields cause duplicate rows without having to make one query per field in the table?

Thanks a bunch!

EDIT: for clarity, the PK will not be enforced and the table is actually a view in a third party system

Comment: If  you're grouping by pk_field AND other_field, `count (distinct other_field)` will always be 1.  did you try running the query with some sample data?  Can't you just set your primary key of your table to be the same as the 'other table' and let your DBMS enforce uniqueness for you?

Comment: If the PK is not unique, it is not a Primary Key. (and how do you *enforce* a PK?)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your code will never return any rows.

Comment: *Duplicates* are not caused by *fileds* but by *rows*. It seems that if you encounter two rows with `(1,A,B,C)` and `(1,A,B,D)`, you want to *blame* the fourth column. But you'll have to think about what to do if you see  `(1,A,B,C)` and `(1,A,B,C)`.  The first think is to *identify* the duplicated `ID`s - which is rather trivial...

Comment: Thanks @MarmiteBomber, that's it exactly, I'm trying to write a query the would show me all of the fields (=columns) that cause duplicate rows and find their ID's. It's not trivial to me, as I'm kind of new to this kind of operation. Once I identified the fields or columns that are incorrectly defined, I can find the functional (business) cause for the duplicates and resolve. Ideally, I would like to have one query that checks all the columns at once, but that's optional

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, primary key should be enforced, and there should be a **unique index** on `(pk_field, other_field)`. Additionally, `other_field` should be `NOT NULL` (so that you wouldn't have "duplicates" for the same `pk_field`, but empty `other_field`.

Doing so, database would handle your problem itself.

---

If you want to do it yourself, well, what can you do? A view? Third party system? What kind of a control do you have over the whole process? If all you CAN do is to find "duplicates", that's kind of *too late*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed this wasn't really clear: I'm busy defining how the view should be. This is the analysis phase. There will be implementation of PK's and indexes at a later stage in the process. Currently, I know I get duplicate rows, I want to find out which column is incorrectly defined in my query so that I can adapt the functional definition of that column to match the grain of the PK. I'm having trouble doing that